# Nothing saving to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am pretty new to making apps with android studio, I got a recommendation to follow a tutorial which I did. Everything was fine until I ran the program and for some reason nothing would save to firebase. I am sorry if it is a simple problem, but like I said, I am totally new to both java and application programming.

I've tried looking through the code line by line and comparing it to the tutorial makers code.

```
    package com.hossain.mylearningproject;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button CreateAccountBtn;
    private EditText Inputname, InputPhoneNumber, InputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog LoadingBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        CreateAccountBtn = (Button) findViewById(R. id. register_btn);
        Inputname = (EditText) findViewById(R. id. register_username_input);
        InputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R. id. register_phone_number_input);
        InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R. id. register_password_input);
        LoadingBar = (ProgressDialog) new ProgressDialog(this);

        CreateAccountBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CreateAccount();
            }
        });
    }


    private void CreateAccount(){
        String name = Inputname.getText().toString();
        String phonenumber = InputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String password = InputPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Write you're name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phonenumber)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Write you're phone number...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Write you're Password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            LoadingBar.setTitle("Create account");
            LoadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while we check the credentialls.");
            LoadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            LoadingBar.show();

            ValidateCredentialls(name, phonenumber);
        }
    }

    private void ValidateCredentialls(final String name, final String phonenumber){
        final DatabaseReference Rootref;
        Rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Rootref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(phonenumber).exists())){
                    HashMap<String, Object> Userdatamap = new HashMap<>();
                            Userdatamap.put("phone number", phonenumber);
                            Userdatamap.put("Username", name);
                            Userdatamap.put("password", InputPassword);

                            Rootref.child("Users").child(phonenumber).updateChildren(Userdatamap)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                        {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Congratulations, you're account has now been created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                LoadingBar.dismiss();

                                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);

                                            }
                                            else
                                                {
                                                LoadingBar.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Connection problem, Please check you're internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                }
                else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "An account with " + phonenumber + " already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    LoadingBar.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please try again using a diffrent phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I expected it to save to firebase using the different "childs", but nothing is saving

I have posted this to SuperUser, but looking at other questions I realized that the odds of someone actually responding was pretty low :/, I also have some great experience getting answers quick and easily here.

Comment: try to log the error so we can help you

Comment: Where in your code are you adding new data to the database? Or you are talking about the update operation?

Comment: have you enabled firebase that is ,auth and database  / firestore?

Comment: There is no logged error, It just wont save anything, both read and write is set to true, and i have nno idea where i am adding new data, Tbh i have still no idea what i am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue i have faced , then i got to know its just beacuse of this rule i was not able to write anything in my database .[image: Check if write rule is set to true . Because it is used to describes if and when data is allowed to be written.] create a data model , say

```
data class User(
var email: String? = "",
var name: String? = "",
var phoneNumber:String? =""
)
```

Now in order to write to firebase database , all you need to do is create an instance of firebase database

```
 database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
```

and then  add values to your model and pass it to database

```
 val user = User("abc.gmail.com, "abc",
        "858689849")
    database.child(userId).setValue(user)
```

In your case .

```
  private void ValidateCredentialls(final String name, final String phonenumber){
    final DatabaseReference Rootref;
    Rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
   ;
    User user =new  User("abc.gmail.com, "abc",
    "858689849");
database.child(userId).setValue(user)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I get all that, but i am still new and very confused. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Check in your firebase console , in database section if rule write is set to true or not. I have attached image .

Comment: i have checked and it is set to true. Both write and read is, but i am very confused of my own code. Where exactly am i even writing to the database?

Comment: addListenerForSingleValueEvent this event is not required while writing to database . As i have mentioned above , you can directly set value with     database.child(userId).setValue(user)

Comment: check the updated answer , in your validate credentials function i have done some changes.